# How to print a phone number of a Contacts in table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, contacts

Check my Code:

```
#import "ContactViewController.h"
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"

@import Contacts;
@import ContactsUI;

@interface ContactViewController ()

@end


@implementation ContactViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   _Contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   _fullName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   _phone    = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self fetchContacts];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) fetchContacts
{
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES) {
            //keys with fetching properties
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
            } else {
                NSString *phone;
                NSString *fullName;
                NSString *firstName;
                NSString *lastName;
                UIImage *profileImage;
                NSMutableArray *contactNumbersArray;
                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                    // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                    firstName = contact.givenName;
                    lastName = contact.familyName;
                    if (lastName == nil) {
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                    }else if (firstName == nil){
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                    }else{
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                    }
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                    if (image != nil) {
                        profileImage = image;
                    }else{
                        profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"acc_sett.png "];
                    }
                    for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                        phone = [label.value stringValue];
                        if ([phone length] > 0) {
                            NSMutableArray *cleanArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

                            // Here 'Activity' is your NSArray. A better name would be 'activity'
                            // (save capitalized names for classes)
                            for (NSString *item in contactNumbersArray)
                            {
                                [cleanArray addObject:[[item componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject]];
                            }

                            NSLog(@"%@",cleanArray);

                            [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
                        }
                    }
                    NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName",profileImage, nil];
                    [_Contacts  addObject:personDict];

                    NSLog(@"%@",phone);
                    NSLog(@"%@",fullName);
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.contacttableview reloadData];
                });
            }
        }
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [_Contacts count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary* personDict = [_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.Name.text  = [personDict objectForKey:@"fullName"];
    cell.Phone.text = [personDict objectForKey:@"phoneNumbers"];

    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [personDict objectForKey:@"userImage"];
     NSData *dataItems=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(cell.thumbnailImageView.image, 0.1);
    NSString *mysavedimage=@"userImage";
    NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *DocumentDirectry=[path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullpathfile=[DocumentDirectry stringByAppendingPathComponent:mysavedimage];
    [dataItems writeToFile:fullpathfile atomically:YES];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}

@end
```

With the help of this code `fullname` and `image` of contacts person is coming on Table view but the Phone number is not coming and I am using a Custom Cell for the display of and one thing after fetching contacts from the simulator in console phone number and full name is both coming on console but on Table View Phone number is not coming.

May be I'm wrong somewhere. Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",phone);` and `NSLog(@"%@",fullName);` are printing something?

Comment: yes in console full name and phone number is coming

Comment: I guess series of output of different full name and number is coming right?

Comment: It looks like you never add the phone to your NSDictionary.

Comment: i have added and on debuging its shows the number

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName", phone,@"phoneNumbers",profileImage,@"userImage" nil];
```

instead of:

```
NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName",profileImage, nil];
```

You are not updating the dictionary with required data.

Comment: After reading that heap of code I just saw this as you posted. "phoneNumbers" key can't be read from his dictionary in `cellForRow:` because he never stuck it in the dictionary.

Comment: but on debuging that line its shows the number that means he is loading bt can't able to display

Comment: " he is loading" - who is 'he' here?

Comment: NSDictionary that i created

Comment: Try NSlogging personDict just above" `NSLog(@"%@",phone);` and `NSLog(@"%@",fullName);`" and show the output.

Comment: 888-555-1212
John Appleseed
 (415) 555-3695
 Kate Bell
 555-522-8243
 Anna Haro
 (408) 555-3514
 Daniel Higgins
 555-610-6679
 David Taylor
 (707) 555-1854
 Hank Zakroff
that kind of output i am getting

Comment: That is name is showing. check the key "`phoneNumbers`". "`phoneNumber`", they should be same.

Comment: i have checked that but still not getting

Comment: Matthew Lawrence Bailey do you know any reason behind that phoneNumbers" key can't be read from his dictionary in cellForRow:

Comment: try using `valueForKey` instead of `objectForKey`

Comment: Finally! Phewwwwww :) Mark as answer if it helped.